# Is it possible to send AWS infrastructure metrics to QuestdB?

Tags: questdb

I have some infra on AWS and I was curious if there's an easy way of getting metrics into QuestDB so I can run some averages or aggregates on daily / weekly / monthly insights. What's interesting for me would be EC2 metrics, load balancer metrics, request count for a service, or other generic cloud resource metrics. Is there an API that I can use to grab these and load them through Python or similar?